# lxml objectify does not call constructors for custom element classes

Tags: python, constructor, lxml, objectify

lxml.objectify does not seem to call the constructors for my custom element classes:

```
from lxml import objectify, etree

class CustomLookup(etree.CustomElementClassLookup):
    def lookup(self, node_type, document, namespace, name):
        lookupmap = { 'custom' : CustomElement }
        try:
            return lookupmap[name]
        except KeyError:
            return None

class CustomElement(etree.ElementBase):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Made CustomElement")

parser = objectify.makeparser()
parser.set_element_class_lookup(CustomLookup())
root = objectify.parse(fname,parser).getroot()
```

Suppose the file being parsed is

```
<custom />
```

I would like this to print "Made CustomElement", but it does not. Can I make it call the constructor?

How is it possible for an instance of the CustomElement class to be created without the constructor being called?

```
>>> isinstance(root,CustomElement)
True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`lxml` docs](http://codespeak.net/lxml/element_classes.html):

> ### Element initialization
>
> There is one thing to know up front.
>   Element classes must not have an
>   `__init___` or `__new__` method. There should not be any internal state
>   either, except for the data stored in
>   the underlying XML tree. Element
>   instances are created and garbage
>   collected at need, so there is no way
>   to predict when and how often a proxy
>   is created for them. Even worse, when
>   the `__init__` method is called, the
>   object is not even initialized yet to
>   represent the XML tag, so there is not
>   much use in providing an `__init__`
>   method in subclasses.
>
> Most use cases
>   will not require any class
>   initialisation, so you can content
>   yourself with skipping to the next
>   section for now. However, if you
>   really need to set up your element
>   class on instantiation, there is one
>   possible way to do so. ElementBase
>   classes have an `_init()` method that
>   can be overridden. It can be used to
>   modify the XML tree, e.g. to construct
>   special children or verify and update
>   attributes.
>
> The semantics of `_init()`
>   are as follows:
>
> - It is called once on
>     Element class instantiation time. That
>     is, when a Python representation of
>     the element is created by lxml. At
>     that time, the element object is
>     completely initialized to represent a
>     specific XML element within the tree.
> - The method has complete access to the
>     XML tree. Modifications can be done in
>     exactly the same way as anywhere else
>     in the program.
> - Python representations
>     of elements may be created multiple
>     times during the lifetime of an XML
>     element in the underlying C tree. The
>     `_init()` code provided by subclasses must take special care by itself that
>     multiple executions either are
>     harmless or that they are prevented by
>     some kind of flag in the XML tree. The
>     latter can be achieved by modifying an
>     attribute value or by removing or
>     adding a specific child node and then
>     verifying this before running through
>     the init process.
> - Any exceptions
>     raised in `_init()` will be propagated
>     throught the API call that lead to the
>     creation of the Element. So be careful
>     with the code you write here as its
>     exceptions may turn up in various
>     unexpected places.

Comment: This soup of words makes no sense to me. What should I do in practice? I tried to replace `__init__(self)` by `__init()`  but it still doesn't get called.

Comment: `_init` not `__init` :)